# If $\mu$ is uniform distributed, what is the distribution of $(2\mu-1)^2$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given $\mu$ sampled from a uniform distribution on interval $[0,1]$, what is the distribution of $s = (2\mu-1)^2$?

*What I've tried:*

1. Let $x=2\mu-1$,
   $$F_X(x)=P(X \leq x)=P(2\mu - 1 \leq x)=P(\mu \leq \frac{x+1}{2})=\frac{x+1}{2}$$
   if $x \in [-1,1]$. Thus,
   $$f_x(x) = \frac{d F_X{x}}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}x$$ when $x \in [-1,1]$. **(Should be $\frac{1}{2}$ as suggested by kcuu)**
2. Let $s = x^2$,
   $$F_S(s) = P(S \leq s)=P(X^2 < s)=?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your notation is a little off. I would say something like "let $Y \sim \mu$ and $X=2Y-1$". Then 
   $$F_X(x)=P(X \leq x)=P(2Y-1 \leq x)=P\left(Y \leq \frac{x+1}{2}\right)=\frac{x+1}{2}. $$
   In any case, when you differentiate this with respect to $x$ to get $f_X(x)$, you do not get $\frac{1}{2}x$, rather just the constant $\frac{1}{2}$. So $X$ is also uniformly distributed, but on the interval $[-1,1]$. This makes sense because the map $\mu \mapsto 2\mu-1$ just shifts and scales the distribution.
2. Again, I would change the notation slightly and say let $S=X^2$. Once you get to $P(X^2<s)$, you can replace this by $P(-\sqrt{s}<X<\sqrt{s})$. Now that you know $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$, you should be able to continue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very appreciate. Just wondered, for part 2, what if $X$ is not a uniform distribution, for example, $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$ for $x \in [0,2]$, can we solve $P(X^2<s)$?

Comment: Yes, you can still write it as $P(X^2<s)=P(-\sqrt{s}<X<\sqrt{s})=\int_{-\sqrt{s}}^{\sqrt{s}} f_X(x) \ dx$, regardless of what $f_X(x)$ is.

Comment: What is the difference between capital letters and lower-case letters here? Population vs. sample? @kccu

Comment: Capital letters are typically random variables, and lower case letters are constants (i.e., real numbers). Note you could also write $F_S(x)=P(S \leq x)= \cdots$ instead of $F_S(s)=P(S \leq s) = \cdots$ and so on.